# How to return closure in most straightforward way?

Tags: python, coding-style

Let's say I want to have a function which produces functions (closures) which multiply their argument by the argument of the factory function.

Example in JavaScript:

```
function get_mult_by(m) {
    return function(x) {
        return m * x;
    }
}
```

In Python I can return `lambda`:

```
def get_mult_by(m):
    return lambda x: m * x
```

But if I want to return a normal function things get more complicated and less straightforward (starting with the necessity of naming the function):

```
def get_mult_by(m):
    def mult(x):
        # do something else
        return m * x
    return mult
```

What are the best practises in that matter?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes much difference.  If the function is a simple expression, I'd probably return a `lambda` as in your first example, but using a named function should not be a problem.  The JavaScript equivalent to the named function case would be:

```
function get_mult_by(m) {
    var mult;
    mult = function(x) {
        return m * x;
    }
    return mult;
}
```

In other words, just think of it as a local that you use to create the return value.

Comment: I think it does make a difference and introduces a boilerplate code.

Comment: @Luke In that case, I guess I don't understand why you posted this question.  If you'd already made up your mind about which you prefer, why waste time asking about it?

Comment: I made up my mind about what I prefer but I don't know how to achieve it in Python. I don't like the fact that Python lacks anonymous functions.

Comment: @Luke I see - So you don't like the fact that you're forced to introduce a local name in order to define an unrestricted function.  I agree that it's an inconsistency in Python, but remember that those names are local and not visible outside of the defining function.

Comment: I'm glad you understand my point of view. :) The thing is that in more real-life examples it isn't that easy to call that inner function.

Answer (score 0):

They are same. To you question, I think using lambda is more pythonic.
Actually if you do not import additional package, you cannot even distinguish them using type function:

```
In [4]: type(lambda x: 1)
Out[4]: function

In [5]: def f():
   ...:     pass
   ...:

In [6]: type(f)
Out[6]: function
```

If you think the complicated way is better, simply go with that and good for you.

Comment: I don't think that complicated way is better, but I don't think I can declare `lambda` with more than one expression.